# Disable the quick links menu on blocks

Tags: routes, blocks, users

I've been searching all morning and cannot find the solution I need. I am sure I am overlooking something.

I want to disable the quick links menu on each block on my drupal 7.23 site when I'm logged in as an Administrator. I don't use them, and they are blocking the links on some small blocks.

How do I turn these off?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2):

They're provided by the core Contextual Links module. If you don't don't need them at all disabling that would be the easiest thing to do.

There's also the [Hide Contextual Links](https://drupal.org/project/hide_contextual_links) module if you want finer-grained control.